# Alias resources for a whole drawable folder in APK

Tags: android, alias, symlink, android-resources

In my app i need to use different drawable depending on screen sizes, not only dpi.

This works good for me, duplicating:

```
drawable-xhdpi --> drawable-large-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi --> drawable-xlarge-mdpi
drawable-xxhdpi --> drawable-large-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi --> drawable-xlarge-hdpi
```

This way i solve the problem (icon size now is pretty fair for all devices i tested), but final apk size obviously grows a lot, symbolic links don't help (files are duplicated inside the APK archive), can i use alias resources for a whole folder?

How to use "cross dpi" alias resources?